# Living on an Isolated Peninsula - Making it Impossible to Leave

Tags: isolation

This is one of a series of questions centered around how an isolated group of people would survive. Each question focuses on a single aspect of survival. Details about the peoples' situation are below:

> In a novel I am developing, a village's worth of people is living on a
>   peninsula. The isthmus connecting the peninsula to the mainland is
>   very narrow, and spanned by a wall, which prevents the people from
>   leaving (there are deterrents preventing them from climbing the wall
>   or otherwise circumventing it). They also cannot swim around the wall. This also means that no land-based
>   animals can cross onto the peninsual from the mainland. The
>   inhabitants have to live with what they have. For the sake of details,
>   assume the peninusla is roughly the size, shape, and location of [Mahia
>   Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahia_Peninsula).

This particular question deals with water being an escape route. For the moment, assume that there is no way for the inhabitants of the peninsula to approach or get across/around/under the wall. The wall is not an option. Flight has not yet been dreamed of (think 13th century). The only remaining option is the sea.

It is very important that the inhabitants have *no way off the peninsula*. This is vital to the novel. The sea cannot be an option for escape, and there can be no doubt about this. What can I do to make sure escape via water is completely out of the question?

For technology purposes, assume the inhabitants of the village are peasants of the medieval era, perfectly adept at building.

---

I've marked the answer by Lu22 because I feels it provides the most air-tight deterrent. Everything else, while great, still has the problem that given enough attempts, someone is *bound* to succeed in the end (granted no one will know that he succeeded, but still).

I would like to mention that the [answer here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/61661/6620) has a convenient index of sorts of everything listed. The [answer provided by Strongo](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/61658/6620) was also a very helpful one, and combined with sea monsters I think would be an awesome combination.

Comment: That's pretty hard considering if it is a fishing village! Alright now I can see the problem... how about undersea volcano throwing up deadly gas bubbles.

Comment: For the sake of the question, can we treat the peninsula as effectively an island? 
Also are cultural/religious reasons ok?
And does it have to be *impossible* to sail off the peninsula, or just extremely difficult/dangerous?

Comment: Is your story based on earth, or is it possibly on an alien or fantasy world? A non-earth location allows for an alien species or some magical danger/barrier in addition to normal earth-type limits to using the sea to circumvent the wall.

Comment: @user6760 Who says it's a fishing village? I don't see that in the question.

Comment: @Jay: my apology I forgot to bold/highlight a certain word/conjunction. To OP: sorry my suggestion is suppose to add a vibrant atmosphere to the village not to crank up the difficulty...

Comment: Try reading some Piers Anthony - he literally wrote the book(s) on isolated isthmi.  http://www.goodreads.com/series/40498-xanth

Comment: This sounds a bit like the set-up for _Destiny's Road_ by Larry Niven.

Comment: How long has this village been there? Because you're going to run into a resource problem before too long. With limited land, the population density is going to explode. Also, are these people farming or what? Because they're going to have to put aside lots of land for crops/livestock.

Comment: @Guran Yes, you can effectively treat the peninsula as an island. There is only a sandbar connecting it to the mainland (possibly with vegetation growing on it). I would greatly prefer for it to be *impossible* to sail off the peninsula. I want it completely out of the question.

Comment: @MarkRipley My world is fantasy, but it is earth-like. I haven chosen not to say that it is fantasy or that there is magic present because I want to keep the details as realistic as possible. Magic is the last resort. I would prefer to use natural causes to achieve everything if I possibly can, as magic creates problems for the plot if it is too plentiful.

Comment: @fiend The village has been there for some time, probably at least seven generations, likely more. A separate question will deal with the resources problem, as I am aware that it exists. The people are likely farming, yes.

Comment: Make it taboo to sail too far. Add sea monsters that live at the continental shelf.

Comment: M. Night Shyamalan's _The Village_ dealt with this very issue. He solved it by a circle of elders creating the illusion of scary monsters living in the surrounding woods.

Comment: And you probably don't need to worry about people leaving the island - you have to worry about people coming _to_ the island and bringing cultural influences and/or disease. And yah, problems go away if it is an island, not a peninsula.

Comment: Ask Donald Trump- He'd probably build a wall and get the people on the opposite side to pay for it.......  :)

Comment: In addition to watching The Village, watch the original Prisoner series with Patrick McGoohan. There are prisoners, and there are wardens, and no-one knows who is which, and anyone being "unmutual" or rebellious is dealt with usually by reconditioning. While the series is a social commentary about how we are all prisoners of one sort or another, there are some interesting technical ideas behind keeping people in.

Comment: The stipulation that it isn't permitted for someone to escape even if nobody knows he escaped makes me wonder why you don't want escape to be possible. Is it purely for the sake of the inhabitants, or is it to prevent the outside world from knowing about them? What would be so wrong about someone escaping but nobody on the peninsula ever finding out about it (and thus continuing to believe it impossible)?

Comment: @Trevortni It is certainly an option for someone to escape and no one being the wiser. The reason I don't like this option though, is because evidence of failure is a far better deterrent than simply *suspected* failure. The reason people can't leave is so that the wall becomes the only option. There is a way out through the wall, which is guarded by... something. That has to be the only option left.

Comment: Is there an intelligence actively trying to keep them on the peninsula? If so, is this intelligence limited to the natives' tech level? If not, it might be worthwhile to have a body that looks exactly like a person that tried to escape "wash up" on the shore a few days after the escape attempt, whether the attempt was successful or not.

Comment: And implanted tracking devices could make it a whole lot easier to avoid embarrassment in this regard.

Comment: This is a fantasy-type novel, so modern technology can't be present. But there is an intelligence keeping them on the peninsula (and guarding the wall), and that intelligence does have access to plenty more 'resources' than the humans do. So your suggestion could work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a whole other route you can go.

**Dependency**

Whoever built the wall did so in order to keep the people in. So how about as an extra measure they had the entire village addicted to a substance only found on the peninsula?

For example a fungus or plant that only grows there under strict conditions, or even a unique tree's (that cannot be propagated) sap.

If not consumed daily the villager suffers extreme withdrawal symptoms or even death. The addiction could be passed from mother to child via breastfeeding, so the villagers can't phase it out.

Alternately it could be a disease affecting everyone (such as HIV), with the substance delaying its potency and allowing a normal life if consumed regularly.

In order to keep the people from hoarding it and being able to travel, the substance would need a very short shelf life.

This would keep the people in the peninsula even without the wall.

Comment: Interesting take on it, Lu22. Thank you. This might not be the exact route I would take, but it's given me some interesting ideas.

Comment: An mentioned in an earlier comment  _Destiny's Road_ by Larry Niven has a lot of interesting thoughts on this problem.  There is also a diet dependency though it is used to control the inhabitants and actually comes from the mainland.  I recommend this book a lot (there was a companion book _The Legacy of Heorot_ that was also a good read).

Comment: Glad I could help.Would like to see the final result.

Comment: "A poison — so subtle, so insidious . . . so irreversible. It won′t even kill you unless you stop taking it." (Dune)

Comment: I didn't even think of Spice. Yeah that's pretty much on par.

Comment: The parallel in the Star Trek universe, to the Dominion's enforcers, the Jem'Hadar, being addicted from birth to Ketracel White, so that they could be kept under control, is pretty obvious too.

Answer (score 25):

### Give them nothing to build a boat out of matched to the nastiest coastline you ever did see.

No wood, no reeds, no beach, just jagged cliffs facing onto the Southern Ocean. Much like Zavodovski Island.
[image: Zavodovski Island]

House building is able to cope with this restriction, it just makes it a bit harder and more expensive to build, as long as they have the stone, but far from impossible. However by taking this option you're effectively limiting the people to stone age technology unless they already have active mining and iron working before the wall was built.

---

The problem here is the breadth of stuff you can use to build a seagoing boat.

- Reeds
- Timber
- Light wood and Hides

Which means that to keep the people on the peninsula you need to prevent them from having any wood, any large animals, any large rivers or accessible shoreline. People will build boats, all they need is half a chance. If you make them desperate enough they'll probably work out how to build a boat out of the skin and bones of their dead relatives.

Comment: I wanted to note that doing this wouldn't necessarily limit technology, as you could have bogs from which peat could be harvested & dried then burned. This puts me in mind of st kilda, which aside from a natural harbour is basically unassailable, and high winds prevent tree growth. islanders living there kept cattle and sheep.

Comment: @jammypeach, I don't know that peat burns hot enough to smelt and it's really hard to mine with stone tools. If you have surface coal and ores then you're ok, but it's not common to have them close to each other. Of course this is fiction so if that's needed then it can happen.

Comment: I'd like to have mining going, as my villagers do need weapons (as in greatsword, not bow & arrow). What would I need to at least get them started in that endeavor?

Comment: This is essentially what eventually isolated and nearly killed off the population of Rapa Nui. No large trees to build boats. A generation or two would be all that it takes before the knowledge on how to build boats is completely lost.

Answer (score 13):

Strong currents moving in wrong direction, extensive coral barrier, wind blows constantly the wrong way, permanent mist, constant heavy surf, etc. There are many shores in the world which are utterly unsuitable for navigation. See for example the Skeleton Coast, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_Coast. Then question remains why don't they simply go *around* the wall...

I guess that it must be important for the plot that the people are on a *peninsula*, probably because at a certain point some enemy comes over the wall, or one or more characters find a way to cross it. Otherwise you could place them on an island or oasis.

Comment: There is only see around the wall.

Comment: Yes but the wall ends in the sea at both ends. They could use small boats or rafts or personal flotation devices and go around unless there are fierce predators in the sea...

Comment: An oasis is much harder to leave than anywhere with a shoreline.

Answer (score 11):

I have yet to see this, so I'll add it as a suggestion: make the sea itself inhospitable to organic materials (including humans).

As in, make it so that the water has some weird chemical composition or there is a microbe/small creature in the water that will eat away and dissolve any organic material in a matter of hours - think barnacles on steroids - far too soon to reach anything beyond the sea and far too late to swim back to shore and tell anybody about the problem.

Now, I don't think you want to kill people who just went for a quick swim, so you could have this toxic element start in the deeper ocean. Basically, you make the area near the shore safe-ish and not have this problem, but if you sail a day or so out then your boat will sink and you will certainly drown or get dissolved by the same effect that destroyed the boat.

13th-century technology is no way capable of making a blue-water vessel out of non-organic materials or of creating a coating which can resist the water's corrosive abilities, so this barrier will completely prevent navigation by water.

You'll just have to make the wall extend 25 miles out to the side from the peninsula, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Also, in case somebody wants to say that they could make a metal or stone boat - even assuming you could somehow make a boat out of nothing but inorganic materials in the 13th century, would you also think to make the boat enclosed and watertight in all directions? Waves splash, and the water eats people, too.

Comment: Like the volcanic acid pool in Yellowstone that devoured a guy who fell in recently.

Answer (score 9):

Note that you don't need specific or modern materials to make very good boats.

"... the traditional umiak was made from a driftwood or whalebone frame pegged and lashed together, sometimes with antlers or ivory, over which walrus or Bearded seal skins are stretched. Oil, usually from seals would be used to coat and waterproof the seams." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umiak

Polynesians travelled thousands of miles across open ocean without access to  modern navigation techniques, using dugout outrigger canoes with no metal parts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynesian_navigation).

So from the frozen north to the tropics in all sea conditions, people are very good at seafaring, but this skill develops over many generations. If the people had been recently deported there from a landlocked place with no navigable rivers then they wouldn't have the knowledge or understanding of boats for some time.

Answer (score 7):

Building up on [Lu22's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/61636/29320)...

#### Unavailability of non-perishable food

The scenario does not require that people are not able to build boats, it just requires that people are not able to *get to any other place* via sea. So, we just need to make sure that the amount of supplies needed to get to any other place is greater than the amount of supplies that can be collected and *stored properly* in a boat.

This means no preservatives (no salt mines, no salt plains, no desalination technology), no milk-based products, no smoking meats, no nut trees, no edible animals on board, no fishing.

It is not needed that the amount of perishable food is exactly zero. We can assume that the available amount of supplies that can be stored for a long time is *small enough* that sea travel is only viable for a very small amount of man-days.

e.g. the islanders spent a few years storing supplies for twenty man-days, and a lone explorer was sent away, but came back after three weeks, starving.

#### Quick-onset scurvy

We all know about [scurvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scurvy), right? The disease that plagued pirates because they didn't eat enough C-vitamin?

The problem with scurvy is that it takes several months for sailors to display symptoms.

Simply create a scurvy-like disease, but with an onset of days instead of months. The disease is easily cured by eating something perishable (the islanders cannot store more than a few days worth of it in a boat), or by being in a completely dry and warm environment.

e.g. the islanders sent lone explorers out to the sea, but they came back after a few days, disoriented and very sick.

#### Lack of navigational tools

Get rid of compass technologies (no deposits of magnetite or similar minerals), and prevent star-based navigation (due to weird climate patterns, there's heavy fog at night out in the sea).

Without compasses or [Iceland spar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunstone_(medieval)), it's pretty much impossible to navigate the sea in a straight line. Watch the few first episodes of [Vikings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikings_(TV_series)) if you need a bit of background on that.

Islanders would still be able to sail around the island, as long as they have a clear view to the landmass. But sail more than 30km away from land, and sailors get lost *fast*.

---

Obviously I'm not addressing the issue of sailing around the isthmus wall, but the OP is explicitly handwaving that issue for this question.

Answer (score 6):

Setting aside that thing about the wall, and taking into account the number of people and the era, you might preventing escape by a combination of a huge predator and a lot of superstition.

Over time, someone will ty to escape. That's only human, so assuming they would not seems to be out of the question.

If you have a large reef around your peninsula, this would provide plenty of food for your village, making life easier, and reduce the pressure to migrate. But the same would be true for large predators.
It would also prevent large vessels from escaping.

Sooner or later someone will fall victim to a large predator. If we are talking about sharks, who normally don't feed on people but just attack because they mistook them for something else, you will have badly mainmed boats and corpses on your sore after an unsuccessful attempt of escaping.

Perils tend to become bigger and more dramatic the more they are reported at night around a campfire. After the second or third attempt, your villagers will have interestin stories of enormous monsters lurking in the sea, hunting humans, tearing them apart, and whatnot.
Also, they will be green, tentacled and fanged, of course.

as a result, joined efforts of leaving will be strongly discouraged. And while from time to time a young hotspur will try to escape, mostly failing very painfully, the only attempts that actually stood a chance would never happen.

What is more, even if our young hero managed to escape, the villagers would never know, and would most likely assume that the monster ate him whole.

So, while it is hard to conceive a way of preventing escape by geographical means, human nature might do the trick of locking them in.

Answer (score 4):

What is on the other side of the wall? If there are hostile people or dangerous animals there, then someone who swims or builds a boat to go around the wall would have no safe place to go.

The water could be full of sharks or other dangerous sea creatures to prevent people from swimming.

People could have the engineering skill to build houses and tools but have no idea how to build a boat. But this gets weak if we're talking about simply getting around a wall across an isthmus. I could easily believe that people can't leave an island because they don't know how to build boats capable of travelling hundreds or thousands of miles. Tougher to believe they can't figure out how to build a simple raft that would take them past a wall. How thick can this wall be? A few feet? Strapping a few logs together so you can sail ten feet doesn't seem all that tough, you'd think someone would think of it sooner or later.

How about something cultural? These people have just never thought of the idea of travelling by water. Or they have a superstition about water, they think ghosts inhabit it or something. Seems to me that sooner or later someone would test such beliefs, but it might be plausible.

Can there be people actively patrolling the waters around the peninsula? Powerful warships quickly sink any boat these people can build and massacre the survivors?

Oh, or how about: the shoreline is steep cliffs. Sure, they could build a boat. But then they'd have to lower it 100 feet to the water and climb down. Then they sail around the wall but to get ashore, they would somehow have to climb from the boat up a 100 foot cliff. It would be possible, of course, but very difficult, the few who try it fail and everyone else just accepts it as impossible.

Comment: All good ideas, but like you said, someone would eventually succeed. These people *really want* to get off the peninsula, so it's plausible that they would keep trying, even ignore their beliefs, to do that. Eventually someone is going to succeed. It needs to be outright impossible for this to happen.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers cover a point I was going to make - if you remove any reliable source of wood from the inhabitants, they have nothing with which to construct a viable ship, and so wouldn't be able to go much of anywhere.

You have said in your question that there is no way *around* the wall, but then gone on to specify the sea as their remaining escape route, so the following works on the assumption that your restriction on their ability to bypass the wall is geared towards land-based methods.

With this in mind, there does remain the possibility that they may be able to cobble together some short-range rafts though to bypass the wall by following the coast to the mainland.

My suggestion to avoid their doing this would be to replace the wall with a mountain range.
Doing so would be able to give rise to incredibly violent storms resulting in any navigation following the coastline to effectively be scuppered by a wall of it's own, in the form of treacherous currents, unpredictable storms, and consistently violent winds.

This could also lead to reefs being present in the area, in the form of the mountain range extending out past the land to either side of the peninsula along the seafloor.
This would provide the dual advantage of further destabilising currents and adding the risk of the sharp rocks in to the equation for someone attempting to traverse the waters in anything from a rickety raft to a full-drafted ship.

Comment: I like your mountain idea, for the storms, reefs, and currents. I don't want the wall to be a mountain (needs to actually be a wall for the novel) but there's nothing saying a mountain range can't be directly *behind* the wall. Are we talking about big snow-capped mountains or simply large hills here?

Comment: @ThomasMyron Well I was thinking enormous snow-capped ones for the sake of replacing the wall as an impenatrable barrier - the bigger and more dramatic they are the more believable the associated effects will be as well. But at the end of the day, it's your world, man :)

Answer (score 4):

I would do either:

- A predator in the sea that will devour anyone that crosses its path.
- Sharp underwater reefs
- Maelstrom's
- Currents pulling a ship against the cliffs
- Alot of fog so nobody can navigate anywhere.
- Lots of rogue waves
- Vulcanic or seismic activity underwater which creates alot of waves. (Tsunami)
- Thunderstorms and bad weather which would be visible from the shore.

The last one is my favorite since it stops people from even thinking of leaving the island.

You could ofcourse combine some ideas to make for a very interesting and dangerous enviroment.

I hope this helped please ask questions or give constructive criticism if you would like to know more or if I missed something.

Answer (score 4):

Why not get psychological? You may have heard of the supposed '5 Monkeys and a Ladder' social experiment. Basically, the original group are punished whenever one attempts something- thus it becomes taboo to do that thing. Finally you end up, a few generations later, with a group that will not do something despite not knowing why. See also: The Village

How to apply this? Your original group of settler, prisoner, whatever, were closely observed. If any tried swimming away then their settlement was raided or someone 'disappeared'. Naturally over time they realised that trying to swim away had a consequence. And the elders, or ruling group now actively prohibit it.

Of course it's not water-tight (ha). But for a bonus there could *actually be something in the water* as others have suggested- but this isn't ever outright said, just hinted at.

Answer (score 4):

Add a continuous fog bank on the mainland that lifts on very rare occasions.

When visible make the land behind the wall all the way up both coastlines appear lethal with lava, scorpions, suffocating smoke, triffids.

Let the local folklore explain the wall as a safety measure rather than imprisonment.  Have the dangers forever creeping around and over the wall requiring vigilance and pruning. Have some of these dangers artificially generated if required.

Add jelly fish, electric eels, piranhas, Candiru :-) , sharks etc to make attempts less tempting, maelstroms, foaming or burning methane.

Also make the shore landing treacherous with venomous sea urchins, jagged sharp cliffs and cannibal tribes.

Let your imagination soar, all you can do is make it hard, the outcast will always find a way.  As mentioned in a comment the book Destiny's Road by Larry Niven has a lot of interesting thoughts on this problem. There is also a diet dependency for the population thought the trace element actually comes from the mainland and is traded with the peninsular inhabitants so they are hostages. I recommend this book as a good reference scenario to try and improve on.

Answer (score 3):

Acid leeches.

They live just offshore, feeding on driftwood, beached whales, and the carcasses of fallen sea birds.  Nothing else swims in those coastal waters - not for long, anyhow.  The leeches' highly developed sense of smell allows them to detect any organic matter - they can eat more or less anything.  When they smell something tasty, they'll swarm over it, latch on, and inject a toxic acid from a spine inside their acid-proof suction-cup mouths.  The wood - or if they're lucky, meat - dissolves quickly, and they drink it up, swelling up to twenty times their original size - up to the size of a loaf of bread.  Afterward, they'll swim along the shoreline, dispersing their eggs over a wide area.  There, the adolescents will hatch, fully formed, and sit dormant, for months if need be, until they scent food.  They exist along the whole shallow coastline, for miles out, at a density of up to ten per square meter.

One bite is enough to kill a child, or seriously weaken a strong adult. Besides having a tendency to bog down and rapidly consume any wooden boats, the leeches also have the unsettling ability to climb and crawl, like huge, horrifyingly fast alien slugs.  Once they've caught the scent, they'll squirm with all their might in pursuit of delicious humans, mindlessly willing to die for the cause.  Therefore in addition to dealing with a heavily encumbered, progressively disintegrating ship, any hypothetical sailors would be engaged in a ceaseless battle of whack-a-mole in which one missed strike could result in their death.

Answer (score 2):

if all the mainland coast for many miles is high cliff, they would just need patrolling to keep people on the island. just make sure no one who makes it to the mainland lives long enough to makes it back to the island.
 the big thing is it may not need to be perfect, just nearly impossible for a few generations, once they believe there is no way off the island they will keep themselves on the island, you don't need to make impossible just too difficult to seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

A small community with humble technology could be thwarted from escape by a combination of factors without having to resort to depriving them of wood.

Imagine strong surf breaking against a rocky cliff of a shore line, making leaving nearly impossible.  If our intrepid explorer gets past the surf, the rocks and shoals, then he or she would be swept out to sea.  Since they can't see anything but water (which can be accomplished by having no no land or other feature for about 50 miles.  The highest point on  Mahia is 1302 feet high.  A six foot tall person on top of the hill could see a little [over 44 miles](http://www.ringbell.co.uk/info/hdist.htm) on a clear day.) there is no obvious destination.

Add to this a dead zone around the peninsula due to Phosphorous(see [Dead zones](http://nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/dead-zone/)), and any explorer swept out to sea would never make it back alive.  In addition, no fish in the water would take away fishing as a motivator for building boats.

There is a reason the wall was built.  Whether to keep them in or keep them out, lore would build up around the wall telling of the horrible creatures waiting on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

These are some of your options to make the inhabitants captive of the peninsula:

**Fast water currents, as suggested by AlexP**

No detail on this, as it has been already covered by AlexP.

**Sea Monsters**

If your world has magic available, then we are talking about true horrors like [krakens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraken), [gorgons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgon) or prehistoric sea monsters such as [pliosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliosaurus), [megalodons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalodon) and [tylosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tylosaurus).

The very sight of these sea monsters in deep waters would keep the people from any thought of getting into deep waters, although they would be free to go fishing in the shallow shore waters (upto the depths of 50 feet or so).

**Lack of required materials for shipbuilding**

Building a ship requires metal. If you don't have any metallic ores on the peninsula, your people would not be able to build any ship in the first place. While they would still be able to hollow out canoes, these would not be large enough to stock a weeks' long reserve of food and water, making long sea journeys impossible.

Comment: You can build big boats entirely out of wood and rope, you don't need metal. You use wooden pegs where you're thinking nails are critical.

Comment: @Separatrix: Yes, but ... how do you chop and shape wood without metal ...?

Comment: Using bits of wood small/light enough that they don't need special tooling besides your hands and maybe some stone tools.

Comment: It's harder and slower, but stone tools can do it. You can get a really good edge on flint.

Comment: @Separatrix: But remember it is only a nearly 240 sq km area. You might not have flint available. Although there are high chances of some sort of a hill or two there, the type of stone might be different than what is required. Also, as I mentioned in my answer, you might be able to build canoe sized boats without metal, but building true seaworthy ship definitely requires metal.

Comment: @YoustayIgo, Let me introduce you to [Treenails](http://www.boat-building.org/learn-skills/index.php/en/wood/treenails/).

Comment: Also you should read up on Thor Heyerdahl and the [Ra expeditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_Heyerdahl#Boats_Ra_and_Ra_II)

Comment: you can shape a boat with just animal bone/teeth, metal just makes it faster.

Comment: Yes, but we are talking about _seaworthy ships_ here, not small boats. As I have already stated, you **can** build small boats without any metallic tools at all. However to build large seaworthy ships, fit for several weeks sailing (as the current will sweep you away from the wall), you would need a sturdy, large ship with enough room for storing food for several weeks for a couple dozen people. _That_ is when you would require metal.

Comment: You haven't read the Ra expeditions. If sailing a papyrus boat across the Atlantic doesn't count as seaworthy, I don't know what you're after.

Comment: @YoustayIgo As was stated in a previous answer, it isn't too difficult to simply build a raft to get around a few feet of wall. My people can't get anywhere near the wall, so it's obviously quite a bit more than a few feet, but the ships hardly need to be sea-worthy.

Comment: You can build a quite large catamaran with no metal.  Take two 70-foot+ trees, hollow them out to make *big* canoes (this can be done with fire - not even stone is required) and strap poles across them to frame out a platform.  You can then build a little house on the deck for shelter and food storage, put up a sail, and you have a decent-sized, totally seaworthy boat.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, best I can come up with would be for the peninsula to have 1) a fairly steep shore/cliffs with the livable land say 20-250 meters above the sea level and 2) be in a crater sea with 3) the isthmus surrounded by that crater sea then by a crater wall 10~20 meters tall with 4) it's connection to the mainland being a (150-200 meters) steep ridge. We could say the unique geography was created by a combination of meteor impact and volcanism. 5) In the crater sea there are many large blue holes letting ocean water easily flow in and out of the crater sea allowing us to have some life in the water. 6) While there are no longer any obvious signs of volcanic activity, CO2 is seeping up and filling the bowl of the crater from the surface of the sea up to say at least 10 meters but below hospitable zone for the peninsula.

This should leave the steep ridge of the isthmus as the only survivable passage to and from the island and give your wall the intended meaning.